# Folland Real Analysis Prop. 7.19b

Tags: measure-theory

This is the proposition and it's proof in the book.

[image]

I tried to track the proof in the book. But $F_n(-N)$ depends on two variables and the proof seems incorrect. I found this counterexample. Let $F_n=0$ for $x\leq -n-1, F_n=1$ for $x\geq -n$ and linear between them. Take $\mu_n$ the associated measure to $F_n$ and $\mu$ the zero measure which is associated to zero function $F$. Then $\mu_n$ converges vaguely to $\mu$ since support of every compactly supported function for sufficiently large n will be greater than $-n$. But $F_n$ does not tend to $F$. Is this counterexample correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please understand that not everyone will have the book right beside them when they read this question. Try to make your question compact, by including all required resources, or at least permalinks to them

Comment: I added an image of the proposition and its proof.

Comment: What step in the proof seems incorrect to you? In my experience, results from a published textbook are usually correct and do not have counter examples. You should also verify that $\mu_n$ is positive in your example.

Comment: @ cpiegore   When he says $F_n(-N)$ tends to zero, this is for a fixed n, but in conclusion he has assumed a form of uniformity. Furthermore in my example positivity of $\mu_n$ is obvious (Since $F_n$ is positive).

Comment: You have $F_n = 0$ for $x \leq -n - 1$. That doesn’t sound like a positive function to me.

Comment: That means nonnegative

Comment: And therein lies the problem. Nonnegative isn't the same as strictly positive. Your $F_n$ isn't positive, only nonnegative, so proposition 7.19 does not apply to your example.

Comment: I told in the sense of Folland, positive means nonnegative!

Comment: That may be true, but that seems highly atypical. Nonnegative ordinarily means greater than or equal to zero, while positive normally means strictly greater than zero. If this is for a course you are taking, you may want to ask the professor about this. They may be able to assist you better.

Comment: Setting aside the issue of whether $F_n$ is supposed to be positive or nonnegative, there are other problems with your question. You say that the author has assumed a form of uniformity. I do not see how this is an issue. The given argument simply shows that both $\lim\sup F_n(a)$ and $\lim\inf F_n(a)$ can be made arbitrarily close to $F(a)$. This forces the conclusion that $F_n$ converges to $F$. Moreover, this convergence is only guaranteed if $F$ is continuous.

Comment: With fixed n, $F_n(-N)$ tends to zero. But the author when taking limsup, has assumed this tendency is independent of n. In other words, he has assumed if N is sufficiently large, for every n, $F_n(-N)$ will be small as desired.

Comment: You should also explain what $M(\mathbb{R})$ is and verify that $\mu, \mu_n \in M(\mathbb{R})$ in your example.

Comment: For one who can answer this question, these are evident.

Comment: Respectfully sir, saying that “these are evident” is not an explanation. You may have indeed found a mistake in the textbook. However, to be certain of that, you must verify that all of the hypotheses of the above proposition are in fact satisfied in your example, including the requirement that $\mu, \mu_n \in M(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, including this information would help to make your question understandable to more people. As others have pointed out, not everyone who looks at your question will have the textbook in front of them.

Comment: My point is that someone who does not know what $M(\mathbb R)$ is or why the mentioned measures are in $M(\mathbb R)$ (which is a well known result in measure theory)  cannot help to solve this problem. For example if you have a question about the limit of a function, will you give the definition of limit in your question? The comment you mentioned was before l put the image of the theorem and in that case my question was ambiguous, so I put the image.

Comment: Your response “someone who does not know this or that cannot help solve this problem” strikes me as arrogant and presumptuous. I personally am not well versed in measure theory. However, it is entirely possible that someone else who reads your question might not immediately recall the definition of $M(\mathbb{R})$, even if they are very knowledgeable. Please understand I am only trying to assist you as best I can, and your refusal to add more information to your question isn’t making it any easier for me, or anyone else, to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: $M(\mathbb R)$ is the space of complex radon measures on real line. My response do not come from arrogance, but l know the subject of my question is very specialized and only experts on measure theory can answer it.

Comment: You should consider asking your question on MathOverflow. They focus on research level math and might provide a better fit for your needs then Math.SE. If you do decide to post your question there, you should make more of an effort to describe what specifically you think is wrong regarding the proof from the textbook, and format your entire question using Mathjax instead of attaching a scan from the book.